# PHP array and json_encode (separated with comma)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am literally cracking my head to covert the PHP array to JavaScript array and convert the same in the correct format. This is what I have

My PHP array is stored in `$data` (this comes from a SQLserver query) which I am converting to a JavaScript array using `json_encode`.

Here is the code `$javaarray = json_encode($data);` When I `echo` the result this is what I am getting

```
{"VERTICAL":"PROVISIONING","dcount":381890}
{"VERTICAL":"BILL DELIVERY","dcount":171169}
{"VERTICAL":"BILLING","dcount":45197}
{"VERTICAL":"RISK AND CREDIT","dcount":51533}
{"VERTICAL":"CUSTOMER ACCOUNTING","dcount":136097}
{"VERTICAL":"AIRTEL MONEY","dcount":7826}
{"VERTICAL":"ANALYTICS","dcount":2946}
{"VERTICAL":"CONTROLS","dcount":5615}
```

Now I want to get the `dcount` part only to feed it back to my jQuery function in the following format

```
[381890,171169,45197,51533,136097,7826,2946,5615]
```

I tried working around with `implode(), join()` but somehow not getting even closer to the above format.

I am posting the

```
$array = array($data); 
print_r($array);
```

result also

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => PROVISIONING [dcount] => 381890 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => BILL DELIVERY [dcount] => 171169 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => BILLING [dcount] => 45197 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => RISK AND CREDIT [dcount] => 51533 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => CUSTOMER ACCOUNTING [dcount] => 136097 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => AIRTEL MONEY [dcount] => 7826 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => ANALYTICS [dcount] => 2946 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [VERTICAL] => CONTROLS [dcount] => 5615 ) )
```

Comment: In which language do you need to build the array of dcounts?

Comment: Java as I need to pass to to my Java function...

Comment: Javascript to be precise..

Comment: I got that rid..thanks

Comment: You didn't provide sufficient information, and it's obvious there's a knowledge gap present. If you use PHP to obtain data from a query, use PHP to construct an array that would give you the desired format. Or, construct the data structure in JavaScript code. These are trivial things. If you want to be spoonfed, please show the output of your PHP array so you can get copypaste code ready for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$dcounts = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
   $dcounts[] = $row['dcount'];
}

$javaarray = json_encode($dcounts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dcounts = json_encode(array_map(function($v) { return $v['dcount'] }, $javaarray));
```

Comment: Is always a good pratice to provide some explanation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = '{"VERTICAL":"PROVISIONING","dcount":381890}
{"VERTICAL":"BILL DELIVERY","dcount":171169}
{"VERTICAL":"BILLING","dcount":45197}
{"VERTICAL":"RISK AND CREDIT","dcount":51533}
{"VERTICAL":"CUSTOMER ACCOUNTING","dcount":136097}
{"VERTICAL":"AIRTEL MONEY","dcount":7826}
{"VERTICAL":"ANALYTICS","dcount":2946}
{"VERTICAL":"CONTROLS","dcount":5615}';

//split data into array
$keywords = preg_split("/[\n]+/", $data);

//convert into proper json format
$jsonobject = implode(',',$keywords);
$jsonobject = '['.$jsonobject.']';

//convert json into array
$array = json_decode($jsonobject);

//for each and save dcount value
$dcount = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    $dcount[] = $row->dcount;
}

//again convert dcount values into json
$dcountjson = json_encode($dcount);
print_r($dcountjson);
```